# Can I use python static variables to communicate between two modules?

Tags: python, static-members

I have two files, one that performs a step in an automated test and a second that stores and emails the test results. Both files are kicked off using a Hudson server and I need the first module to share information with the second, but when I access the static variables in the Reporter module, they have the initial values of 'None'. I've cut the files down to the bare minimum in order to focus on getting the data sharing to work. File one is:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python 

    from reports import Reporter 
    import time

    class Flash_Device(): 
        def Begin_Flashing( self ):
            Reporter.flash_start_time = time.time() 

    if ( __name__ == "__main__" ): 
        flasher = Flash_Device()
        flasher.Begin_Flashing()
```

The second file is the reporting file defined something like the code below:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python 

    class Reporter():
        flash_start_time = None 

        def Report_Results( self ): 
            print "Flash start time:", Reporter.flash_start_time  

    if ( __name__ == "__main__" ):
        reporter = Reporter() 
        reporter.Report_Results()
```

What I was hoping for is that I execute flasher.py, which updates the static variable flash_start_time, and then can access the updated value when executing reporter.py. 
Will that work if I make the method Begin_Flashing() static?

Answer (score 2):

No. The problem is that only one module can be `"__main__"`, therefore only one main stanza will be run.

There's nothing wrong with your code though, except that you import `Monkey_Reporter` when you probably mean to import `Reporter`. And no, accessing it via `reports` wouldn't change anything; they're still the same class.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, I removed 'Monkey_' (I was cutting out my own code and missed that). Thank you for catching that. About the two "__main__" statements, the files are called at different times. I am guessing I will need to write the data to a file to make it accessible to the second file running later in time.

Comment: Yes. Assigning to variables only lasts as long as the interpreter is active.